# Parameters not being set in native query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a  SpringBoot Application and I am trying to do a simple delete using: `@Query(value="", nativeQuery = true)`

My query has dynamic parameters but the parameters are not getting substituted and I am also not getting any error on console.

I tried the NativeQuery with hardcoded parameters and it worked perfectly fine.

Below is the code:

```
@Repository
public interface TypGbPccRepo extends JpaRepository<TypGbPcc, String>{    

@Transactional
@Modifying(ClearAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "delete from T_ST_KFR__TYP_GB_PCC typ where  Trunc(typ.GUELTIG_AB) IN (?1) and typ.GB_PCC IN (?2)" , nativeQuery=true)
void deleteRecords(String datumStr , String gbPccStr);

}
```

I even tried the below query:

```
@Query(value = "delete from T_ST_KFR__TYP_GB_PCC typ where  Trunc(typ.GUELTIG_AB) IN (:datumStr ) and typ.GB_PCC IN (:gbPccStr)" , nativeQuery=true)
void deleteRecords(@Param("datumStr ") String datumStr , @Param("gbPccStr") String gbPccStr);
```

Parameters I am trying to substitute:

**datumStr** - `TO_DATE('12-Sep-2012', 'dd-MM-yy'), TO_DATE('14-Sep-2012', 'dd-MM-yy')`
**gbPccStr** - `'P0','P1'`

I am implementing the above code to delete records based on a Composite Primary key which is a combination of `GUELTIG_AB` & `GB_PCC`. If possible suggest me how to achieve this with a query QueryMethod?

I have been able to delete records based on Primary which is not composite by using QueryMethod but I am unable to do this for a composite Primary key. I have to delete Multiple records in one go.

Below is my POJO

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TypGbPccId.class)
@Table(name="T_ST_KFR_TYP_GB_PCC")

public class  TypGbPcc implements Serializable{


private static  final long serialVersionUID = .....

@Id
@Column(name="GB_PCC")
private String gbPcc = null ;

@Column(name="GB_PCC_desc")
priavte String gbPccDesc = null ;

@Column(name="GB_PCC_SQL")
priavte String gbPccSql = null ;

@Id
@Column(name="GUELTIG_AB")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private String gueltigAb = null ;

}
```

setter & getters here

Comment: Your query looks good to me. I guess you could try using named parameters? e.g. `@Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = :firstname or u.lastname = :lastname")
  User findByLastnameOrFirstname(@Param("lastname") String lastname,
                                 @Param("firstname") String firstname);` See the docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ (example 61. Using named parameters).

Comment: I tried to use it but the thing is ,, I am creating parameter value as String and sending to Repo , whereas one of my column GUELTIG_AB is date field , so it throws an error for mismatch

Comment: PLease hellp.... anybody in the network of Stackoverflow

Comment: You are using it in a wrong way. It will actually be replaced but by the literal string you pass in... So it will insert `'TO_DATE('12-Sep-2012' , 'dd-MM-yy'),TO_DATE('14-Sep-2012' , 'dd-MM-yy')'` literally and not as part of the SQL statement. Basically the `TO_DATE` will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

These are bind parameters, they get passed to the database separately from the SQL statement. They are not used to create a new SQL statement with the parameters concatenated into it.

So what your `Trunc(typ.GUELTIG_AB) IN (?1)` with the given parameter really boils down to is:

> Throw away the time part from `GUELTIG_AB`, convert it to a String using the systems default format, whatever that happens to be and check if the resulting string is contained in the list consisting of a single string: *"TO_DATE('12-Sep-2012' , 'dd-MM-yy'),TO_DATE('14-Sep-2012' , 'dd-MM-yy')"*

What you probably want is closer to:

> Is `GUELTIG_AB` element in the list of dates with the two elements *12th of September 2014* and *14th of September 2014*

Therefore your method should look like:

```
@Modifying(ClearAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "delete from T_ST_KFR__TYP_GB_PCC typ " + 
     "where  Trunc(typ.GUELTIG_AB) IN (?1) " + 
     "and typ.GB_PCC IN (?2)"
     , nativeQuery=true)
void deleteRecords(List<java.sql.Date> dates , List<String> gbPccStr);
```

*Note: you don't need the `@Transactional` annotation on the method, nor the `@Repository` annotation on the interface.*

> I am implementing the above code to delete records based on a Composite Primary key which is a combination of `GUELTIG_AB` & `GB_PCC`. If possible suggest me how to achieve this with a query QueryMethod?

That is not at all what the current query is doing.
If you have rows with the following keys:

```
(d1,p1)
(d1,p2)
(d2,p1)
(d2,p2)
```

You can't delete for example `(d1,p1)` and `(d2,p2)` with this approach, because it will also delete the other two elements.

In order to fix that declare an `@IdClass` on your entity. Specify that in the type parameters for your Repository and use a normal query method.

Comment: Hi @Jens  -- are you suggesting me  to convert the dates which are presently in string to java.sql.date,store each one in List<Java.sql.list> and then pass it along with List<String> GB_pcc To repo ?

Comment: I already have Id class ,,, but I dont know how to use QueryMethod in this scenario ,,your help will be much appreciated ...

Comment: Regarding the first comment: assuming GUELTIG_AB are actually dates, yes that is what I recommend.

Comment: Regarding the second question: See if https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/70d1012ac3ae12f7c7ad4060318ac61a8059db19/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/RepositoryWithCompositeKeyTests.java#L56 helps. If not I recommend creating a new question for that because it is really a different topic than the one asked by 90% of the original question. There you can describe what problems you are experiencing with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a space after datumStr in @Param("datumStr "). Next, change its type to List of String and pass the date strings in your default DB date format.

(You should change the type of gbPccStr to List of Sting as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
 @Query(value = "delete from TypGbPcc where  func('TRUNC',gueltigAb) IN func('TO_DATE',:dateOne,'dd/mm/yyyy') and
func('TRUNC',gueltigAb) IN func('TO_DATE',:dateTwo,'dd/mm/yyyy') and gbPcc IN (:gbPccStr)" , nativeQuery=true)
void deleteRecords(@Param("dateOne") String dateOne ,@Param("dateTwo") String dateTwo, @Param("gbPccStr") String gbPccStr);
```

in dateOne give first date in dateTwo give second date